# el.style.setProperty vs el.style.property

Tags: javascript, performance

What should be used in terms of performance?

- el.style.setProperty

OR

- el.style.property

The only thing I found was this [JsPerf test](https://jsperf.com/dom-style-vs-setproperty) but it lacks runs. Apparently Firefox handles the direct, second style, better and Chrome the first.

Is there some advice what I should use?

Whoever down voted this question, do you bother to comment why this is "opinion based" ?!

Answer (score 2):

To be safe, I would recommend using `el.style.setProperty` because:

- The property names may get changed in future
- The visibility(private) of properties may get changed
- Helpful in tracking the changes with a wrapper function around it
- It is also a good coding practice